# How to validate Html5 date in javascript as systemdate

Tags: javascript, html

I have `input type=date`

```
<input type="Date" name="todate" id="to">
```

in HTML

How to validate the date to `systemdate` and before the current date it must be unavailable to click.I need to validate in `Js` Please provide answers

Comment: What is "systemdate"? How is the input "unavailable" before the current date? [*Input type date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) can have max and min values but isn't necessarily supported everywhere. What have you tried?

Comment: what you mean by system date is that server date ?

Comment: checkout https://momentjs.com/

Comment: System date is currentdate of our system

Comment: Which system? Your server? The user's browser?

Comment: users browser date

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution, first change the following html tag:

```
 <input type="Date" name="todate" id="to">
```

To

```
 <input type="Date" name="todate" id="to" onchange="checkit(this)">
```

The javascript function as follow:

```
function checkit(v)
{
 var now=new Date();
 now.setHours(0);
 now.setMinutes(0);
 now.setSeconds(0);
 now.setMilliseconds(0);

 var userInput=new Date(v.value);
 userInput.setHours(0);
 userInput.setMinutes(0);
 userInput.setSeconds(0);
 userInput.setMilliseconds(0);
 if (userInput.getTime()<now.getTime())
 {
    alert("User input date OLDER current date");
 }
 else
 {
   alert("User input date NOT older current date");
 }
}
```